# Unable to get insert data in MongoDb using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am creating api using Mongodb and nodeJS as a backend.I have created separate database connection file for that and trying to insert data in other file after importing database file  in that.I have `connect.js` file in `db` folder and `category.js` file  in `routes` folder.
But I am getting below error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined
```

Below is my code:

**connect.js**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const dotEnv = require('dotenv').config();

const url = process.env.URI;

const conn = () => {

    MongoClient.connect(url,{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true})
             .then((db) => {

             }).catch((err) => {
                 console.log("error",err);
             });

}

module.exports = conn;
```

**category.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const conn = require('../db/connect');

router.get('/',(req,res) => {

  data = { name:"Digvijay" };

  conn().db("ExpDb").collection("Products").insertOne(data,(err,resp) => {

       if(err){
         console.log("Error",err);
       }
       else{
         console.log("Success");
       }
   });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Someone let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: 1.You can use mongoose npm to as ORM rapper  and set the connection with database
2. You have to create model of respective collection, then you can use  that model by creating Instance of it.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose

Comment: I am using `mongodb` driver here for nodejs can we do that using it as I am not intended to use mongoose as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving everything in the same file. You can segregate the as per requirement.

```
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDb", function (err, db) {
    data = { name:"Digvijay" };
    db.collection('Products', function (err, collection) {
        
        collection.insert(data);
        
        
        

        db.collection('Products').count(function (err, count) {
            if (err) throw err;
            
            console.log('Total Rows: ' + count);
        });
    });
                
});
```

it might help to solve the issue.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#mongodb-method-db.collection.insert

**compatible  issue with insertOne:**

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/#mongodb-method-db.collection.insertOne